# Understanding change of probability density function or proability mass function when "Marginal probability distribution" rule

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

Nobody actually tell me this simple question so I ask here.

For below formula, probability distribution marginalizing, does P(X) and P(X, Y) share same form of PDF or PMF? I assume the PDF or PMF will not be same, but I think it should have some kind of set of PDF or PMF and it works inside it.

Am I right?

[image]

Comment: What is $x$ ? The way you use it it is 1. a random variable, 2. a value it can take, 3. a set that this value can be from . This question is not answerable.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for you opinion. I updated the question to clarify. I intention was to use it as random variable.

Comment: Are $P(X)$ and $P(X,Y)$ not PDFs ? If you clarify this question it should automatically answer your first one: if they share the same form.

Comment: @KurtG. So maybe I'm asking dump question right now. I updated the question again. The probability distribution marginalizing always works... right? And yes P(X) and P(X,Y) will have each pdf maybe f(x) and f(x,y). My question is that will f(x) and f(x,y) have same "form". because it P(X,Y) was created from P(X).

Comment: So maybe what I'm asking is, will f(x) and f(x, y) is actually f(θ;x), f(θ;x,y)

Comment: Marginalizing always works. If $p(x,y)$ is the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ then by definition $\mathbb P(X\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(u,v)\,dv\,du$ which you can read as $p(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x,v)\,dv$. The image you posted lacks the formal defintion of $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and should use MathJax. Apart from that it "looks right".

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for answer. I'll think deeply about your comment and study that I'm currently lack of.